# ¿Medallas para preguntas bien formuladas?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Hay preguntas muy malas que no se han editado bien. Hay otras que no son ni válidas. Pero hay algunas que te puedes flipar de lo bien formuladas que están, con ejemplos, explicaciones detalladas, subrayados, negritas, imágenes y más. [Esta por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59985/cuales-son-los-valores-no-validos-para-la-propiedades-de-estilos-en-ie9) no esta nada mal, pero hay mejores.

¿Existen medallas que premien la buena edición de las preguntas?

Si no es así sería una buena propuesta para incentivar a los usuarios a currarse las preguntas. Aunque por lo normal se debería hacer sin esperar premios.

Comment: ¿Curioso, Inquisidor y Socrático? Cuando preguntas, la pregunta no se cierra y recibe votos positivos, sumas en el contador que con 5 / 30 / 100 te da esas medallas.

Comment: No me refiero a que la pregunta sea bien recibida, sino a que sea una pregunta que en edición esté realmente currada.

Comment: Ajá. Pues no, no hay tal medalla para valorarlas. Al fin y al cabo, es así como deben ser todas las preguntas, ¿no? :P

Comment: Pues como dice la pregunta, es una buena propuesta. Porque aunque debe ser así, no lo es.

Comment: y como se valora eso, desde un script?

Comment: [Pregunta Favorita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) y [Pregunta Estelar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question).

Comment: Un pregunta bien formulada no significa que sea una buena pregunta... pero tu pregunta o propuesta se parte en dos preguntas diferentes: 1. Medallas para preguntas bien formuladas 2. Medallas para una buena edición de la pregunta

Comment: @aldanux: ¿tienes identificado algún caso en SOes de una pregunta bien formulada que no sea buena?

Comment: @Rubén - contra pregunta: ¿No haz visto hasta ahora ninguna? ... Una pregunta puede ser muy bien formulada pero no es útil para la comunidad... por eso hay a veces las discusiones/quejas - _que porque me han cerrado la pregunta_ ... miauu...

Comment: @Marc -Más allá de que no queda claro si es por bien redactada o bien editada, no puedo siquiera imaginarme cómo el sistema podría identificar esos casos, y mucho menos cómo eso resultaría en una interacción positiva en el sitio. Por ejemplo, supongamos que una buena edición es [aquella que fue la última edición](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors). En ese caso, estaríamos fomentando una guerra de ediciones... Para el caso de "bien redactada", por la cantidad de markup? Si no tuvo ediciones? No me parece justo.

Comment: @fedorqui: Las medallas de Curioso, Inquisidor y Socrático más que para dar reconocimiento por una pregunta en particular son, por decirlo de alguna forma, reconocer la trayectoria del miembro. Me parece que las mas pertinentes son Pregunta Interesante, Buena Pregunta y Pregunta Excelente como lo menciono en mi [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1682/65)

Comment: @aldanux: Te pedía el ejemplo porque me parece que entendemos cosas distintas por "bien formulada". Yo entiendo que está implícito que sea una buena pregunta, es decir, además de utilizar apropiadamente elementos de formato cumpla con las recomendaciones de [ask].

Comment: algo que esta bien legible para ti, puede ser dificil de leer para mi. No hay forma de establecer criterios que convenzan a todo el mundo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Mariano no se me había ocurrido lo de la última edición. Eso lo cambia todo y hace imposible al sistema reconocer algo concreto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin duda alguna creo que la recompensa que puede recibir una buena pregunta **son los votos que se otorgan** por ser una pregunta interesante, bien formulada y sobre todo clara y específica, y esto lo defina la comunidad.

Como bien dice [aldanux](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/aldanux) en su [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1681/medallas-para-preguntas-bien-formuladas#comment4801_1681) "*Un pregunta bien formulada no significa que sea una buena pregunta...*" ya que puede tener excelente ortografía, referencias, enlaces, secciones y ejemplos de código pero si el título no es acorde a su contenido o carece de ser objetiva, pierde el sentido de ser una buena pregunta (esto solo por mencionar un par de ejemplos, evidentemente existen muchos más motivos para poder descartarla).

En lo personal considero que, para usuarios nuevos (y no tan nuevos) es más relevante la reputación que las medallas, por eso, es importante motivarlos a saber preguntar y una vez que se den cuenta empezarán a ganar reputación ya que eso es un motivador para seguir participando.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Flxtr coincido con ella.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿existen medallas que premien la buena edición de preguntas?

Sí las hay, y estas son las siguientes:

- [Pregunta interesante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) Pregunta con puntuación de 10 o más
- [Buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question) Pregunta con puntuación de 25 o más
- [Excelente pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) Pregunta con puntuación de 100 o más

La puntuación es el balance de votos positivos/negativos los cuales en el mejor de los casos han sido otorgados valorando de forma integral la pregunta, esto implica la buena redacción (en los artículos de ayuda sobre buenas preguntas se indica que la redacción es importante).

Referencias:

- [Medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)
- [¿Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [¿Por qué es importante votar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder mi cuestión. Te quito el -1 que alguien te ha puesto y que desde mi punto de vista no era necesario.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. Estas medallas interesante/buena/excelente valoran buenas preguntas (que no ediciones). Lamentablemente, muchas veces reciben votos preguntas que son útiles pese a estar muy mal planteadas, pero eso ya es otra historia :)

Comment: @fedorqui: Cuando redacté la respuesta entendí que el OP por edición se refería a redacción no a modificación de la "revisión inicial".